# Jquery Cycle Plugin issue with extending the slideshow "outside" the page boundary

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the Jquery Cycle Plugin ... http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ ... and I'm trying to figure out how these guys:  http://www.flosee.co.uk/ did this.

On their website, and I don't know how to put this into words, but the slider they have going from right-to-left, and if you're display settings are at 1024 x 768, you won't notice anything.  But if they're bigger, like 1280 x 768, or 1920 x 1080, you'll notice that the Jquery slider goes outside the page view, into the edges.  Does this make sense?

I'd like to know how they did this.  Is it just adjusting the Jquery, or a .css adjustment?  With my lack of programming knowledge, I'm just surprised I even installed this successfully, so any clear feedback or advice in this regard would be truly appreciated.

Thanks!

Jason Weber

Comment: Use firebug to inspect the page and find this element: mask-right. It will then become a little clearer to what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm Tony, the owner of flosee :) Glad you like our slider effect, its actually done using three iterations of the slider which are then positioned using css with an opacity overlay. The hardest part was making sure the iterations started one apart so that it gives the impression of being one continuous slideshow across the screen. As a programmer, its not the most elegant of solutions, but it works and I need to get it in place quickly. IF you would like help setting yours up, feel free to send me a message using the contact form on our website.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, Tony.  Yes, my good friend Isabella and I really liked your website, the layout, design, etc., and we discerned you were using the Jquery cycle effect.  But how you managed to manipulate the .css to get it outside the page boundary was pretty darn cool, if I must say so myself.  I have a machine vision, engineering, and robotics company and I just couldn't get it to work like that on our home page -- I got the cycle and various effects, zoom, cycleleft, right, etc.  But thanks again for responding, and I may accept that offer!

Comment: That is just too funny, that you answered my question.  What a small world!